# Creating a Multi-pane layout using android actionbar and navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I'm currently creating an app which can handle different screen support and multi-pane view using fragments. Now I used the default navigation drawer and actionbar using android studio and created two fragments to test for this and layouts for portrait: fragment_1 and fragment_2 which just replaces the container on the MainActivity. But now the problem is how can I implement the fragment_1 and fragment_2 in 1 layout? I Tried to research on the multi-pane development on this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) but I think to properly implement it I need to use an ActivityFragment but in this case I am limited on using just Fragments which is why I'm lost on what to do. Here's the code so far:

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, FragmentMain.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, FragmentAbout.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .commit();
                break;
            /*create the other cases here for navigation*/
        }
    }
```

fragment_main.xml (the 1st fragment)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kahel.main.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_news"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_about.xml (2nd fragment)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kahel.main.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_news"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml (landscape)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kahel.main.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/land_scoop_feed"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_news"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I tried to change the layout it just force close my app. :/

Please let me know what to do or what to search for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran into the exact same problem and after doing a lot of research I was surprised on the lack of documentation for this, in my opinion, common situation. But, after trying a few things I came up with a solution.

My first approach was to replace the Navigation Drawer container with a "root fragment" that at the same time would have two layouts available containing the fragments that I want. The problem was that nested fragments declared on the layout are not permitted.

To overcome this other issue, in my "final layouts" I replaced the Fragment definitions for FrameLayouts and then load the fragments programatically on the "root fragment".

To summarize: You have your Navigation Drawer and upon clicking what you want, you replace your fragment container with a "root fragment". This "Root fragment" has two layouts: a default one and another for landscape. These layouts contain FrameLayout elements arranged as we want that upon initialization are replaced by our "final fragments".

I doubt that this is the best way to achieve the goal of having Multi-pane layouts with a Navigation Drawer but is what I was able to do that best suited my needs. I welcome any suggestions!.

I illustrate the solution with some code.

**MainActivity.java (The one with the navigation drawer)**
    ...

```
void drawerOptionSelected(String option) {

    if(option.equals(XXXX)) {

        Fragment fragment = new RootFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        drawerList.setItemChecked(menuOptions.indexOf(option), true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }
}

...
```

**root_fragment_layout.xml (Default)**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/entries_list_single"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**root_fragment_layout.xml (Landscape)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/entries_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/entries_post"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**RootFragment.java**

```
public class RootFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.root_fragment_layout);

        if(savedInstanceState != null) { //Fragments already loaded, avoid replacing them again
            return;
        }

        ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //IMPORTANT! Use child fragment manager

        if (findViewById(R.id.entries_list_single) == null) { //We are loading the landscape layout
            PostFragment postFragment = new PostFragment();

            transaction.replace(R.id.entries_list, listFragment);
            transaction.replace(R.id.entries_post, postFragment);
            transaction.commit();

        } else { //We are loading the default layout

            transaction.replace(R.id.entries_list_single, listFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```